# GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sda'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted

Tags: partitioning, bootloader, gpt

I have a Ubuntu 14.04.02. As I updated it,there was booting problem on my laptop.After some try it started.How I don't know.So I started fixing my grub as it was also not working.
So after seeing some solutions :
I did:
fdisk is giving me : **WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sda'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.**

and also with 
**Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.**

This is

```
~$ sudo fdisk -l

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sda'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1               1  1953525167   976762583+  ee  GPT
Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.

Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: 995.2 GB, 995190898688 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 120991 cylinders, total 1943732224 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1: 4202 MB, 4202692608 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 510 cylinders, total 8208384 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1 doesn't contain a valid partition table
```

I know something is wrong but don't know what.What is the cause and do I need to fix it? If so, how?

I have checked related links but nothing helped.
The grub bootloader is also not coming and on startup after pressing **ESC Key** settings are coming which are also not working.

Don't know how to fix.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please be more specific in your boot issue. Can you log into Ubuntu?  Do you get any errors?

Answer (score 1):

You already got the answer:

> ```
> WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sda'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.
> ```

So use `parted` instead.

`$ fdisk -l` is for displaying partitions of a msdos disk. Since you have GPT you could use

`$ sudo parted -l`

Comment: You can also use gdisk which is the fdisk for gpt partitioned drives. And fdisk on 16.04, now does support gpt. http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/ or just: `sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda`

Comment: @oldfred Yeah any major disk utility would do.

Comment: @reversiblean so it's nothing to worry about? right?
 i tried both `sudo parted -l ` and `sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda` .

Comment: @TARUNJOSHI Just ignore the warnings. I'm not sure exactly what your problem though..  please be more specific in your questions

Comment: @reversiblean my initials problem was this :  https://askubuntu.com/questions/772716/grub-boot-loaderubuntu-not-working-after-updating

But don't how it booted and then I ran the above command and I found  the problem. So asked .

Comment: @TARUNJOSHI ty for the confirmation. I guess you got the answer here then. Hope you'll find solution to the initial problem as well.

Answer (score 0):

the warning is just a warning. See [WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sda'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/652051/warning-gpt-guid-partition-table-detected-on-dev-sda-the-util-fdisk-doesn)

Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary. 
[Partition does not start on physical sector boundary?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/156994/partition-does-not-start-on-physical-sector-boundary)

also you have another error "Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root doesn't contain a valid partition table"

you ran boot-repair, do you have the bootinfo summary? it is the second option in boot-repair. it asks if you want to upload the summary to pastebin. this could help with fixing your grub

you could also try reinstalling grub2
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing

it might be quicker to boot from live usb and backup your files and reinstall ubuntu

Comment: I didn't ran boot-repair. so no summary.
but my grub bootloader is not starting,I have tried to open GRUB boot loader by pressing SHIFT key while booting but nothing happened.

I will try reinstalling grub2.

Comment: Makes a big difference if you have UEFI or CSM/BIOS. And if drive is gpt, you probably have UEFI boot. Make sure to always boot system & live installer as repair disk in UEFI boot mode. Make sure UEFI is on in UEFI/BIOS and BIOS/CSM boot mode is off. Or if install is BIOS/CSM, only boot in BIOS mode.